InvalidCiphertextException: UnknownError at de_InvalidCiphertextExceptionRes
I am using the correct KMS key, but I keep getting the same 'InvalidCiphertextException' error.
This is my decryption code:
export const decryptField = async (encryptedField) => {
  if (!encryptedField) {
    return null;
  }

  const decryptParams = {
    CiphertextBlob: Buffer.from(encryptedField, "base64"),
  };

  try {
    const res = await kms.send(new DecryptCommand(decryptParams));
    console.log("Decryption successful for field:", encryptedField);
    return res.Plaintext.toString("utf-8");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error decrypting field:", encryptedField, error);
    throw new Error("Decryption error");
  }
};

export const decryptData = async (encryptedData) => {
  try {
    console.log("ENCRYPTED DATA:::::::", encryptedData);
    const decryptedData = {};
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(encryptedData)) {
      if (key === "accountId") {
        decryptedData[key] = value;
      } else if (key && value) {
        const decryptedField = await decryptField(value);
        if (decryptedField !== null) {
          decryptedData[key] = decryptedField;
        }
      }
    }
    return decryptedData;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error decrypting data:", encryptedData, error);
    throw new Error("Decryption error");
  }
};

I can use this key perfectly to encrypt but it doesnt work to decrypt

Can you edit the question and give the full error? Also if you could give a screenshot of the key in the console so the question can be answered better.

Ever found an answer?

This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79126599/4738391
